# Pointer Event Disable anchor tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have to disable the link on an `li` but it should not be disabled all events just disable the link and it will be clickable so i can use hide and show menu function on it

```
#menu-item-747 {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
```

I have used jQuery on this `li` to hide and show other `li` and on this `li` a link is used for another page, I just want to disable link and it will be still clickable to run jQuery toggle.

Comment: Code formatting and spelling.

Answer (score 2):

To disable a link just do

```
$('#menu-item-747 a').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

This won't prevent other actions, just the *default* one of the link element (i.e. following the link).

Comment: Is your link inside the #menu-item-747 element ?