# Remove links from WP Instant Feeds

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I tried to remove the links from the Instagram-Feed at https://staightgang.com/gang by styling the wpmi-item-class (because I didn't manage to adress the "a href") as follows:

```css
.wpmi-item {
    cursor: default;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Nothing happens, the pictures remain clickable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[From the MDN Docs:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

> Note that preventing an element from being the target of pointer events by using pointer-events does not necessarily mean that pointer event listeners on that element cannot or will not be triggered. If one of the element's children has pointer-events explicitly set to allow that child to be the target of pointer events, then any events targeting that child will pass through the parent as the event travels along the parent chain, and trigger event listeners on the parent as appropriate. Of course any pointer activity at a point on the screen that is covered by the parent but not by the child will not be caught by either the child or the parent (it will go "through" the parent and target whatever is underneath).

What you want to do is either remove the `anchor` tags from your template, or use JavaScript to disable them. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272752/pointer-event-disable-anchor-tag)